# Draw String in runnable not working

Tags: java, jframe

I want to draw a string in a runnable, then a few seconds later, add another word to that string, and repeat. The runnable works but it won't drawString?

I've made a mini-application with only what I want if anyone would need to compile and try it.

Here it is:

```
package timer.problem.example;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TimerProblemExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TimerProblemExample() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("Timer Problem Example");
        setSize(950, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerProblemExample();
    }

    public void timer(final Graphics graphics) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int update = 6;
            public void run() {
                update--;
                graphics.setFont(new Font("Splash", Font.PLAIN, 60));
                graphics.setColor(Color.white);
                if (update == 5) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test", 50, 130);
                    repaint();
                }

                if (update == 3) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test Test", 50, 100);
                    repaint();
                }

                if (update == 1) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test Test Test", 50, 50);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }, 0L, 1000L);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);

        timer(graphics);
    }
}
```

Please help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your sample code.

1. Every time you call repaint, a new timer is created. You have so many running (and so often) that each one keeps repainting over the last faster than the UI can update. You can test this by adding `System.out.println("Timer thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());` right before `update--;`. Addidtionally, any changes to the frame (changing it's size by dragging with the mouse, for example) also call paint(), which leads to more timers being spawned.
2. You really shouldn't call `setVisible(true);` until you've set the properties of the JFrame(size, title etc.). It's not a problem right now, but if you intend to add components to it, it'll be an issue.

I've amended your code and this works as per your need.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TimerProblemExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TimerProblemExample() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setTitle("Timer Problem Example");
        setSize(950, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setVisible(true);
        timer(getGraphics()); //call the timer from here, so there's only one running
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerProblemExample();
    }

    public void timer(final Graphics graphics) {
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int update = 6;
            public void run() {
                update--;
                System.out.println("Timer thread: "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
                graphics.setFont(new Font("Splash", Font.PLAIN, 60));
                graphics.setColor(Color.white);
                if (update == 5) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test", 50, 130);
                }

                if (update == 3) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test Test", 50, 100);
                }

                if (update == 1) {
                    graphics.drawString("Test Test Test", 50, 50);
                }

                //Added this section to keep the update variable looping back
                if(update<=0)
                {
                    update = 6;
                }
            }
        }, 1000L, 1000L); //0 Delay for start of timer was spawning lot's of threads in the first second. Slowed it down. Delay isn't needed anymore, but it's useful to have it to see the drawString methods being executed.
    }
}
```

Lastly, it's a good idea not to draw anything directly on the Frame. Add a JLabel to the frame and put the text in that.